# fatal error : sys/syslimits.h No Such file or Directory

Tags: cocos2d-x, scoreloop

I am finding error in compiling my android project containing a sample scoreloop integration in cocos2dx.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation. I figured out it was due to too long directory path. Try to put IDE somewhere else having shorter path.

Answer (score 0):

I had your very same problem. syslimit.h is shipped within the NDK.
Reinstall the NDK and it will work. It worked for me.